# Add image to post using Ajax and Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to add an image to a post with Ajax / Laravel 5.4.

This is my HTML:

```
 <form class="comments-form" action="/upload/comments/{{$post->id}}" method="post" data-id ="{{$post->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<div class="user-picture">
  <img src = '/images/avatars/{!! Auth::check() ?  Auth::user()->avatar : 'null' !!}'>
</div>
<div class="comment-input">
  <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Write a Comment"></textarea>
  <input type="file" name="meme" value="">
</div>

<div class="comment-button">
  <button class = 'add-comment' type="button" name="add-comment">Post</button>
</div>
```

Here is the Ajax code:

```
  $('.add-comment').click(function(){
    var comment_data = $('.comments-form').serialize();
    var post_id = $('.comments-form').data('id');
    var formData = new FormData('.comments-form');// i think here is problem 

    $.ajax({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },

        method: 'POST',
        url: '/upload/comments/' + post_id,
        data: comment_data,formData,

        success: function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
          $('.all-comments').append(data);
        },

        error: function(data)
        {
          console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

This doesn't work – what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The FormData constructor takes a form not a string(you passes a css selector)

```
var formData = new FormData($('.comments-form').get(0));
```

If you use FormData in this way all fields in the form will be automatically added to the FormData object.

If there are items outside of the form fields that needs to be sent use the append method

```
formData.append('comment_data', $('.comments-form').data('id'));
```

When passing a FormData object to jQuery ajax you pass it alone and add processData and contentType set to false

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    },

    method: 'POST',
    url: '/upload/comments/' + post_id,
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    preocessData: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
      $('.all-comments').append(data);
    },

    error: function(data)
    {
      console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data using ajax.. you shouldn't need to put your action in your `form component`

```
<form class="comments-form" data-id ="{{$post->id}}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="user-picture">
    <img src = '/images/avatars/{!! Auth::check() ?  Auth::user()->avatar : 'null' !!}'>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-input">
    <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Write a Comment"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="meme" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="comment-button">
    <button class = 'add-comment' type="button" name="add-comment">Post</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I think if you want to submit your form, better to use jquery submit method

```
 $('.add-comment').submit(function(){
var post_id = $('.comments-form').data('id');
var comment_data = new FormData($(".comments-form")[0]);

$.ajax({
  headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    },

    method: 'POST',
    url: '/upload/comments/' + post_id,
    data: comment_data,
    dataType: 'json'

    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
      $('.all-comments').append(data);
    },

    error: function(data)
    {
      console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: serialize will not work if you're trying t upload an image file

Answer (score -1):

```
you can solve it as the following:
 var formData = new FormData($("#FormId")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload/comments/' + post_id,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         console.log(data);
         $('.all-comments').append(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }); 
    return false;
```

the formData  variable contains all data of the form if you want to send the post id with the data sent you can put hidden field inside form called post id
like this

```
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{$post->id}}">
```

and then apply the above code